# allocating memory to a pointer of an array of structures

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to allocate memory to a pointer of an array of structures but when I compile the terminal sends me *segmentation fault*, this is my code:

```
typedef struct codif {
    unsigned char simbolo;
    int nbits;
    unsigned int codigo;
} codificacion;

codificacion **matcod;
*matcod = malloc(256 * sizeof((*matcod)[0]));
```

Comment: `*matcod=malloc(256*sizeof((*matcod)[0]));`-->`matcod=malloc(256*sizeof(codification *));`

Comment: dereferencing uninitialized pointer `matcod` causes the error

Comment: @chqrlie the problem is the part before `=`

Comment: @user12986714: yes indeed. sorry I misinterpreted your comment, but your first comment does not point an error, merely a style issue.

Comment: @sartrap1: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 1):

This pointer

```
codificacion **matcod;
```

is uninitialized and has an indeterminate value. So dereferencing it like `*matcod` results in undefined behavior.

Maybe you mean the following

```
codificacion *matcod;
matcod = malloc( 256 * sizeof( *matcod ) );
```

Or something like the following

```
codificacion *p;
codificacion **matcod = &p;
*matcod=malloc(256*sizeof((*matcod)[0]));
```

For example if you have a function defined like

```
void f( codificacion **matcod )
{
    *matcod=malloc(256*sizeof((*matcod)[0]));
    //...
}
```

then it can be called like

```
codificacion *matcod;
f( &matcod );
```

Comment: @sartrap1 I have updated my answer. Do you mean to allocate and array of 256 elements?

Comment: sadly for this assigment we are given the type of data that goes into the functions so i cant change  ¨codificacion **matcod;¨ but i do know it points to an array of structures

Comment: @sartrap1 I do not understand what function you are saying.  See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably expected to write a function that takes a pointer to a pointer to this array of structures as an argument. So `codificacion **matcod` is the argument of the function, not a local undefined variable which causes undefined behavior when you dereference it to store the address of the allocated array.

Here is a modified version:

```c
typedef struct codif {
    unsigned char simbolo;
    int nbits;
    unsigned int codigo;
} codificacion;

int allocate_array(codificacion **matcod) {
    *matcod = malloc(256 * sizeof((*matcod)[0]));
    return *matcod != NULL;
}
```

And call this function passing the address of an actual pointer:

```
    codificacion *mat;
    if (!allocate_array(&mat)) {
        printf("allocation error\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always declare your variables with something. Compilers will not always zero-out uninitialized variables. I'm also a big fan of using `calloc` when declaring arrays -- it's a stylistic choice, but especially with arrays of pointers, ensures everything is zeroed out. Uninitialized data can be hell to debug.

```
codificacion **matcod = NULL;
matcod = calloc(256, sizeof(codificacion*));
```

Note that we have created a 256 element array of pointers, not whole structs, and because `**` is an array of pointers to structs and not an array of structs you then need to allocate each struct:

```
for(int index=0; index<256; index++)
  matcod[index] = malloc(sizeof(codificacion));
```

You would then reference your elements with `matcod[index]->nbits`.

Now, what you should do is just implement a flat array of structs and then pass the pointer to that around. Using static allocation, you even get to avoid the `calloc` call.

```
codificacion matcod_array[256] = { 0 };
codificacion *matcod = (codificacion *)&matcod_array;
```

Because you're only passing a pointer to an array of structs as opposed to a pointer to an array of pointers to single structs, you would then reference elements in the array using `matcod[index].nbits`.